# Java jFrame : how do I get all the data from the table that is in the first window to second windows

Tags: java, jframe, jtable

I have a problem with extracting data from jtable. There are many similar questions, but none of them helped.
My problem is as follows:
I have one window(Jframe1) in which the table is located which has 2 columns 
And I open the second window(Jframe2) in which I want to retrieve the contents of the whole table from the number one window(Jframe1) .

My question is how do I get all the data from the table that is in the first window to second windows ?

Comment: Take the `TableModel` from the first table and apply it to the second. Look up `JTable#getModel` and `JTable#setModel`. *"There are many similar questions, but none of them helped"* - some idea of what you've tried would be helpful to prevent us from covering the same ground again, as well as possibly identifying possible issues with your approach - for example, how is the data for the first table create?

Comment: There are many ways to implement this. It´s a architecture question and there are allways X ways to solve this. I would create an adapter like a service which is singleton and static and knows each jframe. if one want all data then the adapter checks which one is asking and send the data from other one. so each jFrame knows this service and so there is no confuseing dependency and you could easyly switch a frame.

Comment: I still do not know how to solve my problem. Can you give an example?
My code snippets that may be useful. 
'DefaultTableModel tab_s_w = (DefaultTableModel) tabela_s_w.getModel()'
This is the code snippet from the first window